# executeScript not populating global variable - Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension and have an array variable `array_out` which is empty. I need this array to be populated with the values of an array that comes from within the `executeScript` on a callback function.

But, for some reason the global array `array_out` isn't being populated, as the `console.log` shows, probably because the chrome function is running after my jQuery?

Any help?

The code I have is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var array_out = [];

    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
            code: " \
                var array_in = ['one', 'two', 'three']; \
            "
        }, function(result){
            array_out = result[0];
            console.log('IN: ' + array_out.length);
        });
    });
    console.log('OUT: ' + array_out.length);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two functions that execute asynchronously.  You provide a callback function for both `chrome.tabs.query` and `chrome.tabs.executeScript` but attempt to access a variable that is only set in the callback method of `chrome.tabs.executeScript`.

In order to ensure that you are accessing `array_out` after it has been initialized, you must place your access code (`console.log('OUT: ' + array_out.length);`) in a separate function that is called at the end of your callback function for `chrome.tabs.executeScript` (or directly in the callback function itself).  By doing so, you still execute code when `$(document).ready()` is called, but also after the two asynchronous functions have invoked their callback functions where the array contents are assigned.

For example:

```
 var array_out = [];

$(document).ready(function(){


    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
            code: " \
                var array_in = ['one', 'two', 'three']; \
            "
        }, function(result){
            array_out = result[0];
            console.log('IN: ' + array_out.length);
            accessArray();
            //you can do stuff with array_out here...
        });
    });
   //console.log('OUT: ' + array_out.length);  //-- array_out will not yet be set here
});

function accessArray()
{
     console.log('OUT: ' + array_out.length);

     //you can do more stuff with array_out here...
}
```

Comment: What about if I put the `array_out` variable outside the `$(document)` function?

Comment: You are right, you would need to do that as well, since  `array_out` will be used in a function outside of `document.ready()`. But the original issue was that it had not been assigned any value.  This can only be guaranteed in the callback function, assuming that `result[0]` has the value you intend.

Comment: Yes, the `result[0]` has the value I need. But the issue here is that I need to have that value added to `array_out` still within the `$(document)` function, because I have other stuff that needs that value after that function.

Comment: Anything that needs the value of `array_out` must be called within the callback function after it has been assigned a value.  So all code that needs to access it would be placed in the `accessArray()` function above.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I need the tags array to be populated still within the `$(document).ready` function. Your solution has it being populated only out of that function, is this possible?

Comment: the `accessArray()` function is only defined outside of the `$(document.ready()` function. It's execution will not take place until it is called inside the callback function, which in turn only executes when `$(document).ready()` is called.  It is essentially the same as placing the code directly in the callback function.

Comment: But If you uncomment the `console.log(OUT:` that is inside the `$(document).ready` function, it still returns 0, so the array_out is still not populated at that stage and I can't use it in the rest of the `$(document).ready` function

Comment: That is right. This is caused by using asynchronous functions. To work around this, you must place any code that you would normally put directly in `$(document).ready()` in the callback function (or `accessArray()`) instead.  The resulting effect is that code in `accessArray()` will only execute when `$(document).ready()` executes AND `chrome.tabs.query()` and `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` have both reached their callback functions.

Comment: Great! I've added a little extra line summing up what we've discussed